# reading data into VHDL

Tags: c, vhdl

I have a C program which performs a lookup table. I insert the size of my matrix by console and I have the output data printed on a text file. Then I should use this data  stored in the text file into a VHDL compiler, to obtain the design of the circuit. Does anybody knows how to read this data using VHDL code?
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to read the data in runtime (as an input pin/bus for the curcuit) or do you need to use it to modify the circuit, i.e. the program itself?

Comment: in each line i have the addresses of the lookup table and the output associated to each one. so i need to read them to obtain the design. if I understood correctly your question I need them as an input

Comment: Reading in the file may not be sufficient - if, say, you need this for synthesis, and you're trying to populate a ROM with some matrix data you generated, file I/O will not work for you. You may need to give more details on your problem to get the answer you need.

Answer (score 2):

If you are fluent in C, add a few printf statements to the start of your program like the following:

```
printf("Package ROM is\n");
printf("   constant Memory : array(0 to 255) of Natural;\n");
printf("end ROM;\n\n");
printf("Package Body ROM is\n");
printf("   constant Memory : array(0 to 255) of Natural := (\n");
```

You may have to tweak printing the actual contentsto generate valid comma-separated VHDL literals (remember, no comma after the last value!)

Then at the end of your program (before closing the file!) add

```
printf("   );\n");
printf("end ROM;\n");
```

Now you can use `Rom.Memory` in your VHDL for either sim or synthesis without worrying about reading files.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by [comment44752557](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192260/reading-data-into-vhdl#comment44752557_28192260), you use the data to specify the wiring. Then your program is essentially partly autogenerated from a template.

VHDL has no such facilities, it specifies a circuit statically. So you need to use some custom step and/or 3rd party tool to generate the program from your "template". [Brian Drummond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28197159/648265) gives one possible way to do this.

If, on the other hand, your circuit includes some programmable element that you need to burn with your data prior to using, then implement the burning procedure with input signals, one of which would be from the file. Alternatively, the element might allow to specify the initial contents of its memory somehow.